# SOLVED Coil not moving in relay

Tags: relay, coil

I am making my own little power-failure warning system. So when the power goes off a LED and buzzer goes on.

Right now it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzGrt.jpg (Sorry for not making it the right way)

But... The coil is not moving. It's in "off" mode the whole time. And that is kinda strange.

So when I was searching for the error I connected the coil to a 9V battery (even if it's a 5v relay). Then the coil was suddenly moving. So I changed the voltage on the adapter to 9v. But still no reaction.

And YES the current is going trough, because I placed a LED after to see if there was current at all. And it was.

So what could be the problem?

Best regards
fiskarn

And well again I connected a LED to the relay-circuit and it was lit. So there's current. Also measured the voltage to 4.9 wich would be enough? But as I said I even tried with 9V and 12V.

Also tried on 3 different relays with the same results.

Comment: Different relays have different activation voltages. Are you sure you are providing enough voltage? Is everything connected correctly? Also, please make an attempt at a better circuit. The one you have provided doesn't really clear anything up.

Comment: Yes. Well as I said this relay is 5V. And also it works when connecting to a 9V battery, but not when changing the adapter to 9V (or even 12..)

Don't really know how to make right circuit examples. But well there's the relay and when OFF I want the LED connected to the battery to light.

Comment: Assuming a standard relay footprint, your drawing only shows one connection to the coil. The other is open.

Comment: Isn't it the coil terminals (http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-hJ9A5YS7bsI/TyKZIRsbr3I/AAAAAAAAAyw/Sl-1OE4n0MA/s1600/Relay2.png) that are the two pins activating the coil? And the one between them are the ground for the N/C and N/O? Or how should I connect for the coil to activate otherwise?

Comment: Oh one of those. It would have been better to give this information at the start. Moving on, your diagram doesn't show a current-limiting resistor for the LED. Do you have one?

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry for that. Kinda electronics-noob making this project to learn so didn't even know there was different kinds of relays haha. Anyway, no I haven't. Here is exactly how it looks: http://imgur.com/a/Ue0oU . So well the battery part is fine but the problem is that the coil is not moving. Even when the LED on that circuit is lit. And no, no resistors. Should I add one somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Solved hehe. Since the LED (wich is a 12v LED) was in series with the relay it didn't work. Changed to parallel and now it works just fine!